# Make TWRP recovery permanent

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp

```
Phone: Xiaomi Redmi 4 prime (unlocked)
Rom (custom): lineage-13.0
```

By entering into fastboot, using the twrp 3.0.2.0 recovery image (made specifically for this phone) and issuing the following commands, I can successfully boot into recovery and use twrp;

```
fastboot flash recovery cofface_twrp_recovery_markw_1121.img
fastboot boot cofface_twrp_recovery_markw_1121.img
```

The problem is, the flashing of recovery is not permanent and as soon as I reboot into system, I will lost the twrp recovery and have to use fastboot and flashing recovery again;

How can I make the twrp recovery permanent?

**Update 1**: If I don't use `fastboot boot cofface_twrp_recovery_markw_1121.img` at the end and use the hardware keys to enter into recovery while the phone is off, it remains at oem logo (MI logo) forever.

**Update 2**: When I was using the stock rom (MIUI 8.2) and applying the above procedure, the first time that twrp showed up, it asked to make the flashing permanent and it became permanent in spite of numerous system reboots.

Comment: Well if you have run flash command from fastboot than  it should be flashed and stay there permanently. Also why do you use boot command after flash if it's flashed (when you use boot command it just boots to recovery from external file it doesn't flash it). Try accessing it with combination of buttons during boot.

Comment: I did that, the problem is after using the hardware keys to enter into recovery (phone is off) it remains at oem logo (MI logo) forever.

Comment: [here](http://www.recovery-mode.com/android/xiaomi-redmi-4-prime.html) it says you should be pressing volume up key when xiaomi logo appears to enter the recovery. What about other users of that phone does anyone have same issue?

Comment: Isn't "Update 2" actually an [answer to your own question](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)? If so, you'd better post it as an answer :) // PS: On many devices, that's the trick: Immediately after flashing, boot into it so it makes itself permanent. Otherwise, the system is reverting back, as you've experienced.

Comment: The thing is in the new custom rom, when booting into twrp recovery even for the first time, it doesn't prompt to make it permanent!

Comment: Many devices will restore the factory the factory recovery on boot, many Moto devices are this way, but it can be circumvented by flashing TWRP and starting it immediately without booting the OS, allowing changes to system, and then going to TWRP's reboot menu and performing a Reboot Recovery, after the reboot in TWRP it makes a change to the recovery replacement script in /system so it doesn't replace TWRP. Might work or might not, if it does I will supply it as an answer.

Comment: It *might* be `/system/recovery-from-boot.p` that's overwriting stock recovery back. I doubt if that exists in LineageOS, though...